# Compiling includes with Ino

Tags: build

I'm attempting to compile this simple [bounce.ino](https://github.com/thomasfredericks/Bounce-Arduino-Wiring/blob/master/Bounce2/examples/bounce/bounce.ino) example with the [ino](http://inotool.org/) tool, but it's giving me the error:

```
Bounce2.h: No such file or directory
```

I've placed it in the same directory as bounce.ino. Why can't it find the header?

Edit: I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: What the is the include code you are using? `#include "bounce.h"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What OS are you using?

If you're in Linux (and some OS X installations) you should note that bounce.h and Bounce.h are two completely different files - you need to make sure you have the capitalization the same in your #include directive as the actual file on disk is.

Comment: This wasn't the exact problem, but you were close. I was doing `#include <Bounce2.h>`, which seems to only look in the library path where it didn't exist. For local includes, I need to do `#include "Bounce2.h"`.

Comment: I was going to suggest that, but then changed my mind as in the normal IDE I think it includes the sketch folder as part of the system paths, so <> and "" have no difference. I guess with inotool it does matter.